# How can i blit more than one of the same thing with only one set of code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

If my ship fires 10 bullets, I need to draw 10 bullets to the screen.
Can I draw 10 of the same thing to the screen without having a chuck of code for each of them and only have one chunk of code?

For example, here is *everything* for the 10 bullets:

## Start of bullets

```
#1

lGun1 = -999
rGun1 = -999

yBul1 = 0
xBul1 = 0

fire1 = 0

b1 = False

ybul1_change = 0
xbul1_change = 0

#2

lGun2 = -999
rGun2 = -999

yBul2 = 0
xBul2 = 0

fire2 = 0

b2 = False

ybul2_change = 0
xbul2_change = 0

#3

lGun3 = -999
rGun3 = -999

yBul3 = 0
xBul3 = 0

fire3 = 0

b3 = False

ybul3_change = 0
xbul3_change = 0

#4

lGun4 = -999
rGun4 = -999

yBul4 = 0
xBul4 = 0

fire4 = 0

b4 = False

ybul4_change = 0
xbul4_change = 0

#5

lGun5 = -999
rGun5 = -999

yBul5 = 0
xBul5 = 0

fire5 = 0

b5 = False

ybul5_change = 0
xbul5_change = 0

#6

lGun6 = -999
rGun6 = -999

yBul6 = 0
xBul6 = 0

fire6 = 0

b6 = False

ybul6_change = 0
xbul6_change = 0

#7

lGun7 = -999
rGun7 = -999

yBul7 = 0
xBul7 = 0

fire7 = 0

b7 = False

ybul7_change = 0
xbul7_change = 0

#8

lGun8 = -999
rGun8 = -999

yBul8 = 0
xBul8 = 0

fire8 = 0

b8 = False

ybul8_change = 0
xbul8_change = 0

#9

lGun9 = -999
rGun9 = -999

yBul9 = 0
xBul9 = 0

fire9 = 0

b9 = False

ybul9_change = 0
xbul9_change = 0

#10

lGun10 = -999
rGun10 = -999

yBul10 = 0
xBul10 = 0

fire10 = 0

b10 = False

ybul10_change = 0
xbul10_change = 0

#End of bullets
gameExit = False

#Start of Game Loop
while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():    
    elif event.key == pygame.K_f:
                #1
                if b1 == False:
                    fire1 = face
                    if fire1 == 1 or fire1 == 3:
                        xbul1_change = 0
                        xBul1 = 0
                        lGun1 = x + 9
                        rGun1 = x + 59
                        if fire1 == 1:
                            ybul1_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul1 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul1_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul1 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul1_change = 0
                        yBul1 = 0
                        lGun1 = y + 9
                        rGun1 = y + 59
                        if fire1 == 2:
                            xbul1_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul1 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul1_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul1 = x - 10
                    b1 = True
                #2
                elif b2 == False:
                    fire2 = face
                    if fire2 == 1 or fire2 == 3:
                        xbul2_change = 0
                        xBul2 = 0
                        lGun2 = x + 9
                        rGun2 = x + 59
                        if fire2 == 1:
                            ybul2_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul2 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul2_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul2 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul2_change = 0
                        yBul2 = 0
                        lGun2 = y + 9
                        rGun2 = y + 59
                        if fire2 == 2:
                            xbul2_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul2 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul2_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul2 = x - 10
                    b2 = True
                #3
                elif b3 == False:
                    fire3 = face
                    if fire3 == 1 or fire3 == 3:
                        xbul3_change = 0
                        xBul3 = 0
                        lGun3 = x + 9
                        rGun3 = x + 59
                        if fire3 == 1:
                            ybul3_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul3 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul3_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul3 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul3_change = 0
                        yBul3 = 0
                        lGun3 = y + 9
                        rGun3 = y + 59
                        if fire3 == 2:
                            xbul3_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul3 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul3_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul3 = x - 10
                    b3 = True
                #4
                elif b4 == False:
                    fire4 = face
                    if fire4 == 1 or fire4 == 3:
                        xbul4_change = 0
                        xBul4 = 0
                        lGun4 = x + 9
                        rGun4 = x + 59
                        if fire4 == 1:
                            ybul4_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul4 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul4_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul4 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul4_change = 0
                        yBul4 = 0
                        lGun4 = y + 9
                        rGun4 = y + 59
                        if fire4 == 2:
                            xbul4_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul4 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul4_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul4 = x - 10
                    b4 = True
                #5
                elif b5 == False:
                    fire5 = face
                    if fire5 == 1 or fire5 == 3:
                        xbul5_change = 0
                        xBul5 = 0
                        lGun5 = x + 9
                        rGun5 = x + 59
                        if fire5 == 1:
                            ybul5_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul5 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul5_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul5 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul5_change = 0
                        yBul5 = 0
                        lGun5 = y + 9
                        rGun5 = y + 59
                        if fire5 == 2:
                            xbul5_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul5 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul5_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul5 = x - 10
                    b5 = True
                #6
                elif b6 == False:
                    fire6 = face
                    if fire6 == 1 or fire6 == 3:
                        xbul6_change = 0
                        xBul6 = 0
                        lGun6 = x + 9
                        rGun6 = x + 59
                        if fire6 == 1:
                            ybul6_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul6 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul6_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul6 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul6_change = 0
                        yBul6 = 0
                        lGun6 = y + 9
                        rGun6 = y + 59
                        if fire6 == 2:
                            xbul6_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul6 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul6_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul6 = x - 10
                    b6 = True
                #7
                elif b7 == False:
                    fire7 = face
                    if fire7 == 1 or fire7 == 3:
                        xbul7_change = 0
                        xBul7 = 0
                        lGun7 = x + 9
                        rGun7 = x + 59
                        if fire7 == 1:
                            ybul7_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul7 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul7_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul7 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul7_change = 0
                        yBul7 = 0
                        lGun7 = y + 9
                        rGun7 = y + 59
                        if fire7 == 2:
                            xbul7_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul7 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul7_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul7 = x - 10
                    b7 = True
                #8
                elif b8 == False:
                    fire8 = face
                    if fire8 == 1 or fire8 == 3:
                        xbul8_change = 0
                        xBul8 = 0
                        lGun8 = x + 9
                        rGun8 = x + 59
                        if fire8 == 1:
                            ybul8_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul8 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul8_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul8 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul8_change = 0
                        yBul8 = 0
                        lGun8 = y + 9
                        rGun8 = y + 59
                        if fire8 == 2:
                            xbul8_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul8 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul8_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul8 = x - 10
                    b8 = True
                #9
                elif b9 == False:
                    fire9 = face
                    if fire9 == 1 or fire9 == 3:
                        xbul9_change = 0
                        xBul9 = 0
                        lGun9 = x + 9
                        rGun9 = x + 59
                        if fire9 == 1:
                            ybul9_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul9 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul9_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul9 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul9_change = 0
                        yBul9 = 0
                        lGun9 = y + 9
                        rGun9 = y + 59
                        if fire9 == 2:
                            xbul9_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul9 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul9_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul9 = x - 10
                    b9 = True
                #10
                elif b10 == False:
                    fire10 = face
                    if fire10 == 1 or fire10 == 3:
                        xbul10_change = 0
                        xBul10 = 0
                        lGun10 = x + 9
                        rGun10 = x + 59
                        if fire10 == 1:
                            ybul10_change = -bulSpeed
                            yBul10 = y - 10
                        else:
                            ybul10_change = bulSpeed
                            yBul10 = y + 88
                    else:
                        ybul10_change = 0
                        yBul10 = 0
                        lGun10 = y + 9
                        rGun10 = y + 59
                        if fire10 == 2:
                            xbul10_change = bulSpeed
                            xBul10 = x + 88
                        else:
                            xbul10_change = -bulSpeed
                            xBul10 = x - 10
                    b1 = False
                    b2 = False
                    b3 = False
                    b4 = False
                    b5 = False
                    b6 = False
                    b7 = False
                    b8 = False
                    b9 = False
                    b10 = False

    #1
    if fire1 == 1 or fire1 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun1, yBul1, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun1, yBul1, 2, 10])
    elif fire1 == 2 or fire1 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul1, lGun1, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul1, rGun1, 10, 2])
    #2
    if fire2 == 1 or fire2 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun2, yBul2, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun2, yBul2, 2, 10])
    elif fire2 == 2 or fire2 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul2, lGun2, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul2, rGun2, 10, 2])
    #3
    if fire3 == 1 or fire3 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun3, yBul3, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun3, yBul3, 2, 10])
    elif fire3 == 2 or fire3 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul3, lGun3, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul3, rGun3, 10, 2])
    #4
    if fire4 == 1 or fire4 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun4, yBul4, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun4, yBul4, 2, 10])
    elif fire4 == 2 or fire4 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul4, lGun4, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul4, rGun4, 10, 2])
    #5
    if fire5 == 1 or fire5 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun5, yBul5, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun5, yBul5, 2, 10])
    elif fire5 == 2 or fire5 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul5, lGun5, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul5, rGun5, 10, 2])
    #6
    if fire6 == 1 or fire6 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun6, yBul6, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun6, yBul6, 2, 10])
    elif fire6 == 2 or fire6 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul6, lGun6, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul6, rGun6, 10, 2])
    #7
    if fire7 == 1 or fire7 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun7, yBul7, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun7, yBul7, 2, 10])
    elif fire7 == 2 or fire7 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul7, lGun7, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul7, rGun7, 10, 2])
    #8
    if fire8 == 1 or fire8 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun8, yBul8, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun8, yBul8, 2, 10])
    elif fire8 == 2 or fire8 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul8, lGun8, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul8, rGun8, 10, 2])
    #9
    if fire9 == 1 or fire9 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun9, yBul9, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun9, yBul9, 2, 10])
    elif fire9 == 2 or fire9 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul9, lGun9, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul9, rGun9, 10, 2])
    #10
    if fire10 == 1 or fire10 == 3:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun10, yBul10, 2, 10])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun10, yBul10, 2, 10])
    elif fire10 == 2 or fire10 == 4:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul10, lGun10, 10, 2])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [xBul10, rGun10, 10, 2])
    
    #1
    yBul1 += ybul1_change
    xBul1 += xbul1_change

    #2
    yBul2 += ybul2_change
    xBul2 += xbul2_change

    #3
    yBul3 += ybul3_change
    xBul3 += xbul3_change

    #4
    yBul4 += ybul4_change
    xBul4 += xbul4_change

    #5
    yBul5 += ybul5_change
    xBul5 += xbul5_change

    #6
    yBul6 += ybul6_change
    xBul6 += xbul6_change

    #7
    yBul7 += ybul7_change
    xBul7 += xbul7_change

    #8
    yBul8 += ybul8_change
    xBul8 += xbul8_change

    #9
    yBul9 += ybul9_change
    xBul9 += xbul9_change

    #10
    yBul10 += ybul10_change
    xBul10 += xbul10_change
```

Can I use one chunk of code and a list or something?
If anyone has an Idea I am all ears.

Comment: You really need to learn about loops and functions.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sorry I didn't make it so clear. I have added everything for the bullets in my question. I know about loops and functions but i didn't see how I could turn all this into something as simple as a loop or a function. If you can then please share, I'm all ears.

Comment: Looks like you've heard of loops and functions (not to mention objects, data structures, etc.) but you don't understand how to apply them. I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two good tutorials to help you learn how to use list and list.pop().

List - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

List.pop() - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_pop.htm

Here is a link to some example code i wrote that may help you to learn as well:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5qxaP8LSuzcQWlucUM4NDUwelk&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem too. What you need is a list.
Here would be an example:
`Bullets = [[BulletX,BulletY,BulletDirection],[BulletX,BulletY,BulletDirection]]`

To add a bullet to the list, you could do:

`Bullets.append([BulletX,BulletY,BulletDirection])`

To display them you use:

`for Bullet in Bullets:
    BulletX = Bullet[0]
    BulletY = Bullet[1]
    BulletDIrection = Bullet[2]
    (PutYourSurfaceHere).blit(BulletImage,(BulletX,BulletY)`

If you didn't know, `for` is a loop which basically means: for every Bullet in Bullets: do the following. Also, the `BulletX = Bullet[0]` is setting the variable `BulletX` to the first part of the list `Bullet`. The list bullet has lists inside of it. Every list inside Bullets is a "bullet". With the loop, you are just accessing the Bullet's data. Also, `Bullet[1]` is accessing the second part of the list of that specific bullet. (because it counts from 0) Then you are just blitting the image of a bullet at its location. To move it, you could do `Bullet[0] += 5`. (That would move it over to the right by 5 pixels.)

To remove a bullet, just put in the loop `Bullets.remove(Bullet)`. That will remove the bullet from the list that it is currently handling.

If you can't figure it out from this, just google a list and loop tutorial for python. (Google them separately.)